# Using QGIS Expression String Builder to display selected multiple layers in a map in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression

In QGIS, in a Map's item properties, inside print composer, there is an option to "lock layers" (display layers) based on an expression, by using QGIS "expression string builder".

I can use as expression the name of a layer in my QGIS project, and that layer will display in the map in the print composer. I'm sure I am missing some basic operator, but how can I display more than one layer? Which function or operator do I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#layers).

The expression must be similar to this:

```
concat ('layer 1', '|', 'layer 2')
```

In QGIS 3.2, you will now see the expected format for any expression. Read more in the [changelog](http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.2.0/#better-expression-debugging-help).

Comment: Thank you. Missed that... and have actually tried the concatenation bar, but without the quotes and the concat function.